# JHipster issue: Cannot find symbols for Entities, Tables

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, maven, jhipster

I recently had to uninstall JHipster and reinstall v7.9.3 since I was using v8.0.0 and it was using a version of Hibernate that was not working for me since I needed TypeDefs. However, after recreating my project, when I run ./mvnw, I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Project.java:[10,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JdbcTypeCode
  location: package org.hibernate.annotations
[ERROR] Project.java:[11,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SqlTypes
  location: package org.hibernate.type
[ERROR] ReviewResource.java:[146,89] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ParameterObject
[ERROR]   location: package org.springdoc.core.annotations
[ERROR] ProjectResource.java:[146,91] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ParameterObject
[ERROR]   location: package org.springdoc.core.annotations
```

I have no idea how to resolve this. Any help?

Comment: How did you regenerate the project?  In a clean directory, from the same jdl file?  You can confirm the jhipster version: `jhipster --version` and get more confiugration details `jhipster --info`

Comment: Yes, and the version is correct - 7.9.3.

Comment: You may have some of the 8.0 dependencies cached and they are not compatible with 7.9.3  .  Can you try clearing your maven cache?